# Model the next expected value in R based on values for previous 3 years

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to the below:

| Area | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 4,000 | 6,000 | 8,000 |
| AreaB | 5,000 | 7,000 | 9,000 |

I'm looking to amend the dataset to predict values for AreaA and AreaB for 2023 based on the three previous years - can anyone please advise? If more data points are required for validity then I can add any number of additional data points but if 3 suffices then that would be ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, and it really depends on what pattern you expect the data to follow. In your example, it looks as though the trend is linear, so you might simply want to get predictions from a linear model.

To do this, it would be far easier if you put your data in a *tidy* format (that is, one row for each observation, with a column for years and a column for values). We can do that as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Area, names_to = 'Year') %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year))
```

Our data now looks like this:

```
df_long
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Area   Year value
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 AreaA  2020  4000
#> 2 AreaA  2021  6000
#> 3 AreaA  2022  8000
#> 4 AreaB  2020  5000
#> 5 AreaB  2021  7000
#> 6 AreaB  2022  9000
```

Now we can do a linear regression on the value according to Year and Area

```
model <- lm(value ~ Area * Year, data = df_long)
```

Using this model, we can get predictions for each area in the next two years by simply creating a data frame of the desired years and areas, then plugging this into `predict` along with our model.

```
newdata <- data.frame(Area = rep(c('AreaA', 'AreaB'), 2), 
                      Year = rep(2023:2024, each = 2))

newdata$value <- predict(model, newdata = newdata)
```

Assuming you want this put back into the original format, we just pivot from long format back to wide format:

```
pivot_wider(bind_rows(df_long, newdata), names_from = Year,
            values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   Area  `2020` `2021` `2022` `2023` `2024`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 AreaA   4000   6000   8000 10000. 12000.
#> 2 AreaB   5000   7000   9000 11000. 13000
```

Reassuringly, we can see that this continues the pattern for each series of increasing by 2,000 every year.

If you *don't* expect your data to change linearly with time, then we would need to know what pattern you expect before being able to advise you.

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>